# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException

Tags: azure, ninject, azure-webjobs

I'm getting this error in my Azure WebJob. Any idea what may be causing it?

I'm using Ninject to handle DI in my Azure WebJobs console app.

I've already set the Bind statements for all my services. Services call repositories. Do I need to bind repositories as well?

When I run the WebJob, it picks up the message in the queue but fails with the following message. I think this is related to Ninject.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception
>   while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage --->
>   System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object. at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceT at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstanceT
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__31.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__2c.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.d__1.MoveNext()

Here's the Program class:

```
class Program
{
   static readonly IKernel Kernel = new StandardKernel();
   static JobHostConfiguration config;

   static void Main()
   {
      BootStrapIoc();
      var host = new JobHost();

      // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
      host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    private static void BootStrapIoc()
    {
       Kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
       config = new JobHostConfiguration
       {
          JobActivator = new MyJobActivator(Kernel)
       };
     }
}
```

Here's MyJobActivator

```
public class BrmJobActivator : IJobActivator
{
   private readonly IKernel _container;

   public MyJobActivator(IKernel container)
   {
      _container = container;
   }

   public T CreateInstance<T>()
   {
      return _container.Get<T>();
   }
}
```

Here's Ninject Bindings:

```
public class NinjectBindings : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(ctx => {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                IConfigurationRoot Configuration = builder.Build();
                return Configuration;
            });

            Bind<IAccountsServices>().To<AccountsServices>();
            Bind<IBlogServices>().To<BlogServices>();

            // Bind<IAccountsRepository>().To<AccountsRepository>();
            // Bind<IBlogsRepository>().To<BlogsRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you binding this to a generic repo? If it helps, I wrote a documentation piece to bootstrap a webjob using Ninject (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/azure-webjobs/2662/azure-webjobs-sdk/16701/dependency-injection-using-ninject#t=201702012246130333719)

Comment: No, not a generic one. It's custom repo I created. I think the whole purpose of using Ninject is NOT to hand-wire things one by one so I thought just binding the services and their interfaces should be enough because repos are referenced inside services so Ninject should be able to pick those up. But I wasn't sure so I posted the question.

Comment: Makes sense, I think you need to bootstrap each repo one by one.

Comment: Really? You think I need to handle it one by one? I though once I handle the services, Ninject would take care of the repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, "`System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object`", it seems that you miss parameter config for ininitializing JobHost in the main function.

If it is that case, please use the following code in the main function. It works correctly.

```
JobHost  host = new JobHost(config)
```

While without `config` parameter to initializing JobHost then I got the same error message.

[image]

The following is my detail steps:

In the main function, changed code as following:

```
IKernel Kernel = new StandardKernel();
Kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var config = new JobHostConfiguration
{
     JobActivator = new MyJobActivator(Kernel)
};
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

I create the demo with your code supplied and change class name **BrmJobActivator**  to **MyJobActivator**.  And in the NinJect Bindings.cs load function just keep following codes:

```
  Bind<IAccountsServices>().To<AccountsServices>();
  Bind<IBlogServices>().To<BlogServices>();
```

Then it works correctly for me.

[image]

Comment: Tom, I really appreciate your response. I think you're right and I have pretty much what you're suggesting in my code but still getting the same errror on Azure -- even though it works fine locally. I posted all the code I have in my WebJob here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995465/webjob-failing-on-azure-but-locally-running-fine